# Get array of all strings between two characters (Regex + JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm not expert in Regex and I want just do this thing.
Create this array :

```
["[1+5]", "1+5", "[2*[1+1]+5]", "2*[1+1]+5", "[1+1]", "1+1"]
```

from this string :

```
"blalbla[1+5] blabla [2*[1+1]+5] blalbla"
```

I have tested a lot of methods, I have a headache...
Here the link to test what I have did: https://jsfiddle.net/a47e60pd/1/

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you have arbitrary level of nested brackets, you cannot use a regex. JS regex does not support recursion. Or, you may want to use [`XRegExp.matchRecursive`](http://xregexp.com/api/#matchRecursive).

Comment: What's the point of this exercise? Are you going to evaluate those, ie. replace `1+1` with `2`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the information.

Comment: @georg Yes, then I use eval method. Oriol's answer is satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regex. Just use a loop.

```js
function* parse(str) {
  var indices = [];
  for(var i=0; i<str.length; ++i) {
    if(str[i] === '[') {
      indices.push(i);
    } else if(str[i] === ']') {
      let idx = indices.pop();
      yield str.slice(idx+1, i);
      yield str.slice(idx, i+1);
    }
  }
}
console.log([...parse("blalbla[1+5] blabla [2*[1+1]+5] blalbla")]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is possible with clean regex like this:

```
/\[[^[]+\]|\[.+?\]([^[])+\]/g
```

Explanation:
Group 1: `\[[^[]+\]` find brackets that start and finish without other brackets.

Or `|` 
Group 2:

`\[.+?\]` find the start of brackets, until the finish brackets, and `([^[])+\]` continue find all characters that not "[" until the last "]"

```js
var ExpToReturn;

var text = "blalbla[1+5] blabla [2*[1+1]+5] blalbla";

var str = text.match(/\[[^[]+\]|\[.+?\]([^[])+\]/g);

ExpToReturn = (str);

alert (ExpToReturn);
```

Comment: Your method is also good. But I prefer Oriol's method. Thanks a lot for your useful answer